# Transparent GIF image not transparent in web, has background

Tags: web, photoshop, gif

the img I made is suposed to be transparent but when I upload it to my web page it has a dark blueish background, just don't understand why .. please help, how can I check if its fully transparent ?

Answer (score 0):

what browser? transparency in gif is just a color that you set as transparent and the browser must interpret it as transparent. Some older browsers don't work with it. If it displays correctly in any modern browser such as chrome for example, then the transparency is correctly set in your gif.

Comment: Chrome;  how can I check if its fully transparent ? what format is better  then ?   png, gif, png24, jpeg ? @Leo

Comment: I think you can't create a transparent jpeg. Your question was about transparent gifs. What do you really want to do?

Comment: Actually I think png32 is the best choice, because it supports the full range of transparency and helps creating much more smooth results without jagged edges.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another different software to save the GIF or a different method of selecting transparency, for example, by mask instead of by color. Or try a PNG format instead.